# Вывод данных из двух таблиц

Tags: php, mysql

Просьба помочь в решении следующего вопроса.

Есть две таблицы:

**Таблица users:**

```
id, user, pass

1, user1, pass1

2, user2, pass2

3, user3, pass3
```

**Таблица log:**

```
id, id_users, date_time, ip

1, 1, 2017-03-11 22:22:22, 192.168.1.1

2, 1, 2017-03-11 22:32:22, 192.168.1.1

3, 1, 2017-03-11 22:42:22, 192.168.1.5

4, 2, 2017-03-11 23:00:22, 192.168.1.10

5, 2, 2017-03-11 23:05:22, 192.168.1.10

6, 3, 2017-03-11 23:55:22, 192.168.1.22
```

Как вывести данные из двух таблиц я знаю.
Мне нужно, чтобы по каждому юзеру была статистика его заходов и не было дублей в зависимости от кол-ва записей в таблице log, т.е. к каждому юзеру в отдельной таблице все ip.

Сейчас происходит так:

```
user1, 2017-03-11 22:22:22, 192.168.1.1

user1, 2017-03-11 22:32:22, 192.168.1.1

user1, 2017-03-11 22:42:22, 192.168.1.5

user2, 2017-03-11 23:00:22, 192.168.1.10

user2, 2017-03-11 23:05:22, 192.168.1.10
```

и т.д.

GROUP BY не предлагать, т.к. все будет сгруппировано и в результате я увижу только один ip.

Мне бы хотелось, чтобы вывод был таким образом:

```
user1, 2017-03-11 22:22:22, 192.168.1.1

       2017-03-11 22:32:22, 192.168.1.1

       2017-03-11 22:42:22, 192.168.1.5


user2, 2017-03-11 22:22:22, 192.168.1.1

       2017-03-11 23:00:22, 192.168.1.10

       2017-03-11 23:05:22, 192.168.1.10
```

Очень прошу помочь. Заранее спасибо

Comment: вывод на экране вы можете делать как угодно, например не выводить имя пользователя если в предыдущей строке был точно такой же. а больше ни чем имеющийся и желаемый вывод вроде не отличаются

Comment: А можно пример?

Answer (score 0):

Функция [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT u.user, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(l.date_time, ' - ', l.ip))
FROM users u
JOIN log l ON l.id_users = u.id
GROUP BY u.id
```

Запрос вернёт весь лог для юзера в одной строке, позже его можно `explode`ить для вывода.

---

Впрочем, можно также просто отсортировать по `ORDER BY u.user, l.date_time`, чтобы логи одного пользователя шли подряд.
Тогда перед выводом, можно проверять, что в текущей строке пользователь, как в предыдущей и не выводить его.

---

Также можно произвести группировку результатов выборки самостоятельно:

```
$list = [['user': 'alice', 'date_time': 0, 'ip': '::1'], ['user': 'alice', 'date_time': 2, 'ip': '::1']];
$grouped = [];
foreach ($list as $row) {
  if (!isset($grouped[$row['user']])) grouped[$row['user']] = [];
  grouped[$row['user']][] = $row;
}
unset($list);
```

Теперь несложно каждому пользователю вывести необходимый `rowspan`, например.

Comment: Если вы думаете что group_concat то что нужно, то проще закрыть вопрос по дублю потому как вопросы с таким решением проходят ежемесячно. И кстати в MySQL `||` вроде не конкатенация